# Separate Controller for Admin Panel in REST API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently working on REST API using Spring Boot. Let's say i have product service with basic functionality in controller. There are two roles in user which are normal user and admin.

example:addProduct, getProduct, updateProduct, deleteProduct

User can only access getProduct endpoint and admin can access all endpoints.

Which one is better apporoach?

first approach:

api/v1/products/ -> do all get, post, delete, patch

second approach:

api/v1/products/admin -> get, post, delete, patch

api/v1/products -> get

Comment: If you want a formally correct REST API, then you definitely want to take the first approach.  The path component of a REST request is supposed to always be a resource.  Since `admin` is not a resource (you're not operating on an admin), it shouldn't be part of the path.  I would have the API be the same for both kinds of users, but most commands fail if the authenticated user is not an admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a **Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)** wherein each user has a role. and each role has permissions, e.g. get_post, delete_post, and so on. As your application gets bigger in scope, you can have fewer routes in this way.

Example situation: if a user posted a resource on api/v1/products, the system will check if the user has a "create_product" permission. If he has no access then your api should return 401 unauthorized